# .NET MVC4 Facebook, Google & Twitter Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, dotnetopenauth

I am using .NET MVC4 and I want a auth extension Facebook, Google & Twitter.
I downloaded DotNetOpenAuth 4.1 but I can't find any example on the web on how to integrate it with my app and have a Login form of the providers in my view.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why the question was down voted. It'd be nice if people explained why they did that when they do it. I upvoted to even it out as I have this question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything.  MVC4 includes this functionality in the default Internet Template.

Just generate a new MVC4 apps, choose the internet template, run it and log in with your facebook id.

Comment: You mean Internet Application?
I am not sure you are right. I am talking about .NET MVC4 Web App.

Comment: Yes, the DotNetOpenAuth integration is there if you are using the RTM release of MVC 4. Create an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and select the "Internet" project template. Run the new application and click on the Login link, you'll see the space where OAuth providers will be listed. You can go into the App_Start AuthConfig.cs file to configure the services.